# Adding brackets around the type of the return value from malloc

Tags: c, malloc, declaration, parentheses, variable-declaration

When I hope to allocate some memory using malloc, I tried doing it in the following ways:

```
(char *) conc_str = (char *) malloc(1);
char *conc_str2 = (char *)malloc(1);
```

However, the first one gives me an error saying that "identifier "conc_str" is undefinedC/C++(20)". Why does it throw an error while the 2nd way of mallocing memory doesn't? What's the difference between using `(char *)` vs using `char *`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
(char *) conc_str = (char *) malloc(1);
```

Is a statement which performs a cast on an existing variable called `conc_str` and attempts to assign a value to the result of the cast.  This is invalid for two reasons: `conc_str` has not yet been defined and the result of a cast cannot be assigned to.

While this line:

```
char *conc_str2 = (char *)malloc(1);
```

Is a *definition* for the variable `conc_str2`, specifying `char *` as its type, and initializes it with the value returned by `malloc`.

Also, you shouldn't cast the return value of `malloc` as it's not required and can mask other problems in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You may enclose in parentheses a declarator but not a type specifier.

So for example these declarations are valid

```
char *conc_str2;

char * ( conc_str2 );

char ( *conc_str2 );

char ( * ( conc_str2 ) );
```

though the compiler can issue a message that there are used redundant parentheses.

As for an expression like this

```
(char *) conc_str
```

then there is used casting of the already (somewhere) declared (if it is indeed declared) variable `conc_str` to the type `char *`.

Thus this record

```
(char *) conc_str = (char *) malloc(1);
```

is not a declaration but an assignment statement that moreover is incorrect statement even if the variable `conc_str` was already declared because the operand  `(char *) conc_str` is rvalue that may not be assigned.